# Creation of Model based on JSON response from API in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I'm calling an API which gives the response as JSON. I'm trying to deserialize the JSON object I'm confused to create a model based on the response. My response will be as follows with the code :

Code:

```
IRestResponse res = client.Execute(request);
//res.content will be ginving me response as follows :
```

response in string format :

```
"[{\"9305\":{\"headerData\":{\"poNum\":\"9305\",\"vendorId\":\"15963\",\"vendorName\":\"Enlow  Construction\",\"poValue\":\"20881.00\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"utilValue\":\"10440.00\",\"dateCreated\":\"1/2/2020 5:44 am\",\"numInvoices\":\"1\",\"requestorName\":\"Sagun, Ernest\",\"requestorEmail\":\"abc.com\"},\"items\":[{\"item\":\"\",\"itemDesc\":\"TQH - Painting - Site Improvement- 50% down required $10440.50\",\"rate\":\"\",\"amount\":\"20881.00\",\"quantity\":\"\"}]},\"9316\":{\"headerData\":{\"poNum\":\"9316\",\"vendorId\":\"14742\",\"vendorName\":\"Optum Health Financial Services\",\"poValue\":\"-723.75\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"utilValue\":\"-723.75\",\"dateCreated\":\"1/2/2020 6:24 am\",\"numInvoices\":\"1\",\"requestorName\":\"Sagun, Ernest\",\"requestorEmail\":\"Ernesto.Sagun@C3connect.com\"},\"items\":[{\"item\":\"\",\"itemDesc\":\"Employee Benefits\",\"rate\":\"\",\"amount\":\"-723.75\",\"quantity\":\"\"}]},\"9317\":{\"headerData\":{\"poNum\":\"9317\",\"vendorId\":\"9840\",\"vendorName\":\"Global Equipment Company\",\"poValue\":\"1194.34\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"utilValue\":\"145.50\",\"dateCreated\":\"1/2/2020 6:30 am\",\"numInvoices\":\"1\",\"requestorName\":\"Sagun, Ernest\",\"requestorEmail\":\"Ernesto.Sagun@C3connect.com\"},\"items\":[{\"item\":\"\",\"itemDesc\":\"Site Improvement Project - Budgeted Capex Spend - Thermostat Guards, Wheelchair and Compact Refrigerator\",\"rate\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1194.34\",\"quantity\":\"\"}]},\"9318\":{\"headerData\":{\"poNum\":\"9318\",\"vendorId\":\"9840\",\"vendorName\":\"Global Equipment Company\",\"poValue\":\"658.16\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"utilValue\":\"539.70\",\"dateCreated\":\"1/2/2020 6:31 am\",\"numInvoices\":\"1\",\"requestorName\":\"Sagun, Ernest\",\"requestorEmail\":\"abc.com\"},\"items\":[{\"item\":\"\",\"itemDesc\":\"Site Improvement Project - Budgeted Capex Spend - Thermostat Guards\",\"rate\":\"\",\"amount\":\"658.16\",\"quantity\":\"\"}]},\"9322\":{\"headerData\":{\"poNum\":\"9322\",\"vendorId\":\"13423\",\"vendorName\":\"Universal Protection Service, LP dba Allied Universal Security Services\",\"poValue\":\"57150.73\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"utilValue\":\".00\",\"dateCreated\":\"1/2/2020 6:44 am\",\"numInvoices\":\"1\",\"requestorName\":\"Sagun, Ernest\",\"requestorEmail\":\"abc.com\"},\"items\":[{\"item\":\"\",\"itemDesc\":\"US security guard services for Dec 2019\",\"rate\":\"\",\"amount\":\"57150.73\",\"quantity\":\"\"}]}}]"
```

When I tried to create a model by using the online converter :
https://json2csharp.com/json-to-csharp
I got the following classes :

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
    public class HeaderData    {
        public string poNum { get; set; } 
        public string vendorId { get; set; } 
        public string vendorName { get; set; } 
        public string poValue { get; set; } 
        public string currency { get; set; } 
        public string utilValue { get; set; } 
        public string dateCreated { get; set; } 
        public string numInvoices { get; set; } 
        public string requestorName { get; set; } 
        public string requestorEmail { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Item    {
        public string item { get; set; } 
        public string itemDesc { get; set; } 
        public string rate { get; set; } 
        public string amount { get; set; } 
        public string quantity { get; set; } 
    }

    public class 9305    {
        public HeaderData headerData { get; set; } 
        public List<Item> items { get; set; } 
    }

    public class HeaderData2    {
        public string poNum { get; set; } 
        public string vendorId { get; set; } 
        public string vendorName { get; set; } 
        public string poValue { get; set; } 
        public string currency { get; set; } 
        public string utilValue { get; set; } 
        public string dateCreated { get; set; } 
        public string numInvoices { get; set; } 
        public string requestorName { get; set; } 
        public string requestorEmail { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Item2    {
        public string item { get; set; } 
        public string itemDesc { get; set; } 
        public string rate { get; set; } 
        public string amount { get; set; } 
        public string quantity { get; set; } 
    }

    public class 9316    {
        public HeaderData2 headerData { get; set; } 
        public List<Item2> items { get; set; } 
    }

    public class HeaderData3    {
        public string poNum { get; set; } 
        public string vendorId { get; set; } 
        public string vendorName { get; set; } 
        public string poValue { get; set; } 
        public string currency { get; set; } 
        public string utilValue { get; set; } 
        public string dateCreated { get; set; } 
        public string numInvoices { get; set; } 
        public string requestorName { get; set; } 
        public string requestorEmail { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Item3    {
        public string item { get; set; } 
        public string itemDesc { get; set; } 
        public string rate { get; set; } 
        public string amount { get; set; } 
        public string quantity { get; set; } 
    }

    public class 9317    {
        public HeaderData3 headerData { get; set; } 
        public List<Item3> items { get; set; } 
    }

    public class HeaderData4    {
        public string poNum { get; set; } 
        public string vendorId { get; set; } 
        public string vendorName { get; set; } 
        public string poValue { get; set; } 
        public string currency { get; set; } 
        public string utilValue { get; set; } 
        public string dateCreated { get; set; } 
        public string numInvoices { get; set; } 
        public string requestorName { get; set; } 
        public string requestorEmail { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Item4    {
        public string item { get; set; } 
        public string itemDesc { get; set; } 
        public string rate { get; set; } 
        public string amount { get; set; } 
        public string quantity { get; set; } 
    }

    public class 9318    {
        public HeaderData4 headerData { get; set; } 
        public List<Item4> items { get; set; } 
    }

    public class HeaderData5    {
        public string poNum { get; set; } 
        public string vendorId { get; set; } 
        public string vendorName { get; set; } 
        public string poValue { get; set; } 
        public string currency { get; set; } 
        public string utilValue { get; set; } 
        public string dateCreated { get; set; } 
        public string numInvoices { get; set; } 
        public string requestorName { get; set; } 
        public string requestorEmail { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Item5    {
        public string item { get; set; } 
        public string itemDesc { get; set; } 
        public string rate { get; set; } 
        public string amount { get; set; } 
        public string quantity { get; set; } 
    }

    public class 9322    {
        public HeaderData5 headerData { get; set; } 
        public List<Item5> items { get; set; } 
    }

    public class MyArray    {
        public 9305 9305 { get; set; } 
        public 9316 9316 { get; set; } 
        public 9317 9317 { get; set; } 
        public 9318 9318 { get; set; } 
        public 9322 9322 { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Root    {
        public List<MyArray> MyArray { get; set; } 
    }
```

But How all the class names 9305,9316,9317... Are dynamic. How can I make model easily to deserailize the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should refactor the generated code,

```
public class HeaderData    {
    public string poNum { get; set; } 
    public string vendorId { get; set; } 
    public string vendorName { get; set; } 
    public string poValue { get; set; } 
    public string currency { get; set; } 
    public string utilValue { get; set; } 
    public string dateCreated { get; set; } 
    public string numInvoices { get; set; } 
    public string requestorName { get; set; } 
    public string requestorEmail { get; set; } 
}

public class Item    {
    public string item { get; set; } 
    public string itemDesc { get; set; } 
    public string rate { get; set; } 
    public string amount { get; set; } 
    public string quantity { get; set; } 
}

public class RootElement    {
    public HeaderData headerData { get; set; } 
    public List<Item> items { get; set; } 
}
```

Use `Newtonsoft.Json` to deserialize the response

```
var jsonString= "[{\"9305\":{\"headerData\":{\"poNum\":\"9305\",\"vendorId\":\"15963\",\"vendorName\":\"Enlow  Construction\",\"poValue\":\"20881.00\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"utilValue\":\"10440.00\",\"dateCreated\":\"1/2/2020 5:44 am\",\"numInvoices\":\"1\",\"requestorName\":\"Sagun, Ernest\",\"requestorEmail\":\"abc.com\"},\"items\":[{\"item\":\"\",\"itemDesc\":\"TQH - Painting - Site Improvement- 50% down required $10440.50\",\"rate\":\"\",\"amount\":\"20881.00\",\"quantity\":\"\"}]},\"9316\":{\"headerData\":{\"poNum\":\"9316\",\"vendorId\":\"14742\",\"vendorName\":\"Optum Health Financial Services\",\"poValue\":\"-723.75\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"utilValue\":\"-723.75\",\"dateCreated\":\"1/2/2020 6:24 am\",\"numInvoices\":\"1\",\"requestorName\":\"Sagun, Ernest\",\"requestorEmail\":\"Ernesto.Sagun@C3connect.com\"},\"items\":[{\"item\":\"\",\"itemDesc\":\"Employee Benefits\",\"rate\":\"\",\"amount\":\"-723.75\",\"quantity\":\"\"}]},\"9317\":{\"headerData\":{\"poNum\":\"9317\",\"vendorId\":\"9840\",\"vendorName\":\"Global Equipment Company\",\"poValue\":\"1194.34\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"utilValue\":\"145.50\",\"dateCreated\":\"1/2/2020 6:30 am\",\"numInvoices\":\"1\",\"requestorName\":\"Sagun, Ernest\",\"requestorEmail\":\"Ernesto.Sagun@C3connect.com\"},\"items\":[{\"item\":\"\",\"itemDesc\":\"Site Improvement Project - Budgeted Capex Spend - Thermostat Guards, Wheelchair and Compact Refrigerator\",\"rate\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1194.34\",\"quantity\":\"\"}]},\"9318\":{\"headerData\":{\"poNum\":\"9318\",\"vendorId\":\"9840\",\"vendorName\":\"Global Equipment Company\",\"poValue\":\"658.16\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"utilValue\":\"539.70\",\"dateCreated\":\"1/2/2020 6:31 am\",\"numInvoices\":\"1\",\"requestorName\":\"Sagun, Ernest\",\"requestorEmail\":\"abc.com\"},\"items\":[{\"item\":\"\",\"itemDesc\":\"Site Improvement Project - Budgeted Capex Spend - Thermostat Guards\",\"rate\":\"\",\"amount\":\"658.16\",\"quantity\":\"\"}]},\"9322\":{\"headerData\":{\"poNum\":\"9322\",\"vendorId\":\"13423\",\"vendorName\":\"Universal Protection Service, LP dba Allied Universal Security Services\",\"poValue\":\"57150.73\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"utilValue\":\".00\",\"dateCreated\":\"1/2/2020 6:44 am\",\"numInvoices\":\"1\",\"requestorName\":\"Sagun, Ernest\",\"requestorEmail\":\"abc.com\"},\"items\":[{\"item\":\"\",\"itemDesc\":\"US security guard services for Dec 2019\",\"rate\":\"\",\"amount\":\"57150.73\",\"quantity\":\"\"}]}}]";

var elements = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string,RootElement>>>(jsonString).FirstOrDefault();
```

and then, you can do the straightforward manner to get the properties. For example:

```
elements["9305"].items.FirstOrDefault()?.amount
```

Comment: Can you please provide me the models how to define based on your code ?

Comment: Yes, Done the same, But it's throwing an exception as like "Error in converting the..." response.

Comment: Facing this error :   "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'C3ConnectLib.Item' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '[0].9305.items', line 1, position 294."

Comment: I think you test the code before the change

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HeaderData    {
    public string poNum { get; set; } 
    public string vendorId { get; set; } 
    public string vendorName { get; set; } 
    public string poValue { get; set; } 
    public string currency { get; set; } 
    public string utilValue { get; set; } 
    public string dateCreated { get; set; } 
    public string numInvoices { get; set; } 
    public string requestorName { get; set; } 
    public string requestorEmail { get; set; } 
}

public class Item    {
    public string item { get; set; } 
    public string itemDesc { get; set; } 
    public string rate { get; set; } 
    public string amount { get; set; } 
    public string quantity { get; set; } 
}

public class YourModelName    {
    public HeaderData headerData { get; set; } 
    public List<Item> items { get; set; } 
}
public class Root    {
    public List<YourModelName> MyArray { get; set; } 
}

 Root obj= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root> (orderJson);
  List<YourModelName> array=obj.MyArray;
  HeaderData data=array[0].headerData;
  List<Item> items=array[0].items;
```

this gives you first item in the array.... hope you know how to loop and get
data further.

Comment: If this is the model, How can we go for Deserialize ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JObject from Newtonsoft.Json.Linq in this way:
JObject json <- your json.

```
HeaderData headerData = jsonToHeaderData(json["9318"]["HeaderData"]);
```

Where jsonToHeaderData is:

```
    protected HeaderData jsonToHeaderData(JToken json)
    {
        if (json != null && json.ToObject<object>() != null)
        {
            return json.ToObject<HeaderData>(JsonSerializer);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

In this way you can serialize all the data by dynamically entering the first number and modelling HeaderData and Item.

I hope to be proved helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Dynamic keyword if you just want to test the Json response. It will store the response which you are trying to get from the API without the need of storing them in model class. Good for testing and demo purposes.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-type-in-c-sharp/